# How to remove non existing store from Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I know how to remove a store from Outlook by using `_namespace.removestore([folder])`, which is working fine.

But what can I do if the store does not exist as a physical file on disc anymore? In that case every acces to the store produces a messagebox `Store couldn't be found. Please select one` and a file open dialog is shown. Even an assignment like `store = stores[i]` checks whether the file exists and causes this message.

As a user I can right click on the store in Outlook an select `close [PST]`. Everything is ok after that. But i would like to do this programmatically. Can anyone tell me how to do this or someone has a good website to this topic?

Comment: I don't know about Outlook programming, but in general, shouldn't you check if that store exists first, and then try removing it?

Comment: That's my problem: I want to remove the store from Outlook in case it doesn't exist on harddisk anymore.

Comment: Sounds like sync between hard disk and Outlook store?

Comment: I would assume a foreach look that says something like, go through all the stores in outlook and check if it exists in hd, if it doesn't then store.Remove(), or something.

Comment: Unfortunately the Remove Method requires a folder object, which i can't retrieve, because the store does not exists and therefore every access to it produces the message mentioned above.

Comment: So how come the physical folders are removed in the first place?

Comment: The Pst lies by default in %temp% and the user deleted the contents of this directory.
Currently I am trying to write a clean Pst file at runtime from the projects ressources. Hope this will do the trick.

Comment: Sounds like it shouldn't be writing in the temp in the first place, to avoid causing that. Sorry I don't have an answer on how to solve this!

Comment: (Now) I know that this was not the best decision to put it there, but it's hard to change it now. My solution to write a blank pst file from the ressources is luckily working, so my question can be closed. (Anyone knows how?)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in Extended MAPi (C++ or Delphi) - you will need to find the PST store row in the message service table (`IMsgServiceAdmin::GetMsgServiceTable`) based on the store entry id, then call `IMsServiceAdmin::DeleteMsgService()`.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) for that - [RDOPSTStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).`Remove` will remove the store from the profile even if the PST file does not exist.